# What is the smallest set of privileges required for an assembly to run?

Tags: c#, assemblies, appdomain

If I'm loading an assembly using `Assembly.Load(Byte[])` in a new `AppDomain` what is the smallest set of privileges that said `AppDomain` must have in order to run?

Comment: I would imagine you need the highest possible privilege level to do that.  Consider what the code does... it's basically loading arbitrary code from an unknown source.  That could be used in all sorts of malicious ways.

Comment: Not for the hosting assembly, but rather the hosted assembly.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx) for this?  It says that the hosted assembly runs at the same trust level as the hosting assembly, which kinda makes sense.

Comment: Right, but I'm creating a new `AppDomain` before actually loading the new assembly. It's the `AppDomain` configuration I'm concerned with.

Comment: Have you tried it?  It wouldn't surprise me if the same is true for the target AppDomain (apples and apples), and it would be easy enough to check.

Comment: But, uh, wouldn't that would negate the purpose of making the `AppDomain` security configurable in the first place? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setappdomainpolicy.aspx)

Comment: That method is obsolete. :)  In any case, it would follow that you could set it for less privileges than the hosting domain, but not more.

Comment: You can still set the `PermissionSet` using `AppDomain.CreateDomain` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766.aspx). My question is what is the *least* number of permissions I can give an `AppDomain`/`Assembly`, and still have it run? (In addition to being able to load it using Assembly.Load)